# Implementing connected imageicon in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout

This is basically a UI question. I am trying to implement something like this in my app.

[image: Image taken from Cleartrip App]

I am able to implement independent circles in blue and grey  but i am not able to implement the line connecting them.

Comment: so what have you done so far?

Comment: i would just put a drawable in to an image view that ranges over the full height of the cell?

Comment: You have to use 9 patch image where you can set bg color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers so far will work, but I think there's a better answer.

You will want to use a state drawable as the background for the list item, something like this should get you closer to your goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/complete"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/pending"/>
</selector>
```

You can make modifications to this in order to match your exact logic. Use 9-patch drawables with the bar at the bottom and whitespace to the right acting as the scaling portion.

In your adapter, use View.setSelected(true) to mark the views that represent completed legs of the trip.

Comment: thanks. would you please elaborate on how to use the 9-Patch drawables?

Comment: A quick overview is here (what it is): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and here (how to make it): http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `View` with your required width and height

```
<View
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#000000"
 />
```

Replace #000000 with your color

Comment: the problem is there are gaps between the lines introduced due to the default divider between rows.